# T-SQL capture the date based on changed status

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables on daily basis one is master table another one is transaction table. I have to check master table status in transaction table, there are 3 types of status in transaction table like pending, in-transit and received; if status is changed, then how to capture changed date and find the day from change to today's date?

Comment: Table structure, sample data and expected results would be extremely helpful here...

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: And also good information here: [SO - How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi bhavna, please provide (1) Queries to CREATE your tables including indexes. (2) Queries  to INSERT sample data. (3) The desired result given the sample, as text or image of excel for example. (4) A short description of the business rules, and how you got 1-2 of the results. (5) Which version of SQL Server you are using (this will help to fit the query to your version).